# Kubernetes / Docker application dependency patterns

Tags: docker, kubernetes

My project has an application server and a C++ library. The library is not dependent on the application server. The vendor has a Docker image for the application server. I need to deploy a C++ library that needs to be accessible from each of the application server nodes/pods.

I've written a Dockerfile that builds on the vendors image, compiling and copying the libraries into place. It works, however, every time there's a new version of the application server I need to build my C++ library again from scratch. Given the lack of dependencies these doesn't seem optimal.

Naively, what I was expecting was to be able to build the C++ library into an "empty" image and mount that (like a filesystem) in each pod. That way the server and the library are maintained separately.

Is building on the vendor Dockerfile the "right" way to architect this? Or is there a solution more like my "idealised" vision?

I expect the answer is obvious and I just need the right terminology to search for... pointers very much appreciated.

Comment: can't you use something like ansible / chef / puppet to manage your deployments?

Comment: @jcuypers You mean running it on top of Kubernetes or instead? The requirement I was given was to use k8s.

Comment: You could run it on top of yes.   to manage your deployed server and/or kubernetes itself.   checkout the plugins.  you could even have dynamic inventory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Kubernetes you have at least two options to manage the library separately from container image:

1. [Init containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/). If you put your library to external resource you can use `Init container` to [download](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/) it and put inside the application server's pod file system.
2. [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#types-of-volumes). You can also put the library to a network storage and attach it as a volume in [ReadOnlyMany](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) access mode to the application server pods.

Comment: Looks like init containers is the right solution going forward — thanks for the suggestion. (Feels like my use case isn’t one that’s well addressed by Kubernetes currently. While this is a better solution than I found, it doesn’t feel terribly elegant. Just me?)

Answer (score 1):

As you said you can build the C++ library into an "empty" image. And for all the deployments you can use this as base image. This way you can avoid building library for every deployment.

Ex: Build image with C++ Library. Lets call this lib-img.
When vendor is building image, vendor can use lib-img as base image, you can also add additional dependencies to lib-img which are needed by vendor.

You can also use init containers to pull the library on the pods.

Comment: Switching the order is definitely a useful option but I don’t think it’s an option for me, since I don’t have control over the vendors image. I upvoted, though, since this is still a useful suggestion.

Comment: ok. Can you build the lib and upload to say S3. The image can have a script that pulls the lib before the container starts ?